# FormData() converts files to String

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, form-data

I cannot send the original data object from my form through axios to Spring Boot as is is a single object and Spring boot cannot get the @RequestParams for it. Therefore, I am putting the data a FormData object so that it can be sent to a Spring Boot application, however, whenever I append a file to the FormData object, it converts my file array to a string.

Here is the code:

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
        console.log(data, "Form data");

        let payload = new FormData();
        payload.append("JobName", data.JobName);
        payload.append("CandidateFile", data.CandidateFile);
        payload.append("ReferenceFile", data.ReferenceFile);
        console.log(...payload, "Payload")

        for(let pair of payload.entries()) {
            console.log(typeof pair[1]);
        }

        ...
```

In the console, data comes back with the data object, with files included:

> {JobName: 'JobName', ReferenceFile: [File], CandidateFile: [File]}

The FormData payload, in the console, is:

> (2) ['JobName', 'JobName']
>
> (2) ['CandidateFile', '[object File]']
>
> (2) ['ReferenceFile', '[object File]']

And all three typeof of the payload values come back as:

> String

Is there any way I could send the files through with FormData?

I have tried using the files both in an array, and out, yet it still gives the same result.

Comment: How are you defining `data.CandidateFile` in the first place?

Comment: It is a file upload from my ui that is being put into an array (need this for possible multiple file functionality). I can see it coming through fine when I inspect it from the object data, as well as everything inside it correctly.

Comment: I mean a proper example not a description. It *looks* like `data.CandidateFile` is an "array of one file" and not "one file", but you haven't provided a [mcve]